# How to insert multiple rows sequentially

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning hibernate, and I have a hibernate class TestAuthor, and i am inserting records into that class using 'HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist' command as shown in the below code.
the problem is, when i run that code and then check the entries in the table I found that onlx the last record was inserted. In other words, after running the below code, the table TestAuthor contains only the last record inserted
which is 'testAuthor.setmFName("Nour"); testAuthor.setmLName("Youssri");'

why the only the last row is inserted while the other were ignored, and how to solve this issue?

**hibernate code**:

```
    TestAuthor testAuthor = new TestAuthor();

    testAuthor.setmFName("Ali");
    testAuthor.setmLName("gamil");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);
    testAuthor.setmFName("Fatma");
    testAuthor.setmLName("Joss");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);
    testAuthor.setmFName("Lobna");
    testAuthor.setmLName("Nolan");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);
    testAuthor.setmFName("Ahmed");
    testAuthor.setmLName("Ghadi");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);
    testAuthor.setmFName("Nour");
    testAuthor.setmLName("Youssri");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);
```

**update**

**TestAuthor**:

```
@Entity 
@Table(schema = "afk_owner", name = "testauthor")
public class TestAuthor {

@Id
@Column(name = "authorid")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =  
"sequencegen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequencegen", sequenceName = 
"afk_owner.testauthor_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer mAuthorID;

@Column(name = "FNAME")
private String mFName;

@Column(name = "LNAME")
private String mLName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private List<TestBook> books;

public Integer getmAuthorID() {
    return mAuthorID;
}

public void setmAuthorID(Integer mAuthorID) {
    this.mAuthorID = mAuthorID;
}

public String getmFName() {
    return mFName;
}

public void setmFName(String mFName) {
    this.mFName = mFName;
}

public String getmLName() {
    return mLName;
}

public void setmLName(String mLName) {
    this.mLName = mLName;
}

public TestAuthor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}
```

Comment: Don't reuse the same object to represent different rows of data. Create a new `TestAuthor` for each row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have many objects, I suggest that you do a batch insert

```
    List<TestAuthor> listTA = new ArrayList<>();

    //create TestAuthor objects and add them to listTA       
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction trx = session.beginTransaction();
    int i = 0;
    for( TestAuthor ta : listTA){

    session.persist(ta);
    //or session.save(ta);
    i++;
    if (i % 50 == 0) {
          session.flush();
          session.clear();
    }

    }
   trx.commit();
   session.close();
```

Your hibernate configuration file should also include

```
 <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>;
```

Additionally, persist works only on new objects, which means you'll get an exception if you try to insert the same object/entity twice.

The purpose of flushing and clearing the session has to do with releasing the memory associated with it and having Hibernate insert exactly 50 rows (batch size) into the database before processing other records. 
Because we're using transaction control , the actual rows are not (permanently) saved/persisted until a commit on the transaction object is called (flush will just prepare data for insert)

Comment: Yes, SO is famous for having stupid people that downvote without giving a reason why.

Comment: would you please tell me, is .flush and . clear are different than HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist?

Comment: persist() is similar to save() and has nothing to do with either flush() and clear().

Comment: I think this is good approach. If you could explain why the same instant `testAuthor` should not be used for multiple times as the author did; explain why you need to flush every N items; and reformat your code; il would be even better. I upvote your answer.

Comment: That's a list of TestAuthor objects (List<TestAuthor> listTA)

Comment: and i think you forgot to reset the value of the conter i each time you flush and clear..right?

Answer (score 2):

once you do first time

```
    testAuthor.setmFName("Ali");
    testAuthor.setmLName("gamil");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);
```

It creates new row in DB(as its transient object, No id is assigned to TestAuthor) and assign id to testAuthor and object becomes persistent. After that if you repeat it it just updates the same row

if you want to insert another row create another transient object

```
    testAuthor = new TestAuthor();
```

See [Object states in Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html)

Comment: ok..there is no id assigned because the id is aprimark key added as constraint and its value increases via a sequence

Comment: can you post the class TestAuthor

Comment: mAuthorID(because of annotation `@Id`) is the id here which will be populated automatically once entity is saved in DB